# How to extract two pdf files from an XML file?

Tags: xml, delphi, pdf, delphi-2010

In response to a request in Post, I get an xml file that contains two pdf files (as in the example that I enclose).
My problem is that I can not extract the files above.

```
--MIMEBoundary_90d05142045ade9e6fce7c43cb81856f3bd2630a9667b995
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.a0d05142045ade9e6fce7c43cb81856f3bd2630a9667b995@apache.org>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body><a:RispostaCDPDWSBeanProduciRetro xmlns:a="http://virtuale.ws.cdpd.aci.it/data" xmlns="http://ws.cdpd.aci.it/data">
<a:Result
   <esiti>
      <codice>0</codice>
      <descrizione>ESITO OK</descrizione>
   </esiti>
   <tipoEsito>1</tipoEsito>
</a:Result>
<a:FilePdf1>
 <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:b0d05142045ade9e6fce7c43cb81856f3bd2630a9667b995@apache.org"/>
</a:FilePdf1>
<a:tipoDocumento>2</a:tipoDocumento>
<a:FilePdf2>
  <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:40d05142045ade9e6fce7c43cb81856f3bd2630a9667b995@apache.org"/>
</a:FilePdf2>
</a:RispostaCDPDWSBeanProduciRetro>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundary_90d05142045ade9e6fce7c43cb81856f3bd2630a9667b995
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <b0d05142045ade9e6fce7c43cb81856f3bd2630a9667b995@apache.org>
   %PDF-1.4........pdf1 body...........%%EOF
--MIMEBoundary_90d05142045ade9e6fce7c43cb81856f3bd2630a9667b995
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <40d05142045ade9e6fce7c43cb81856f3bd2630a9667b995@apache.org>
   %PDF-1.4........pdf2 body...........%%EOF
--MIMEBoundary_90d05142045ade9e6fce7c43cb81856f3bd2630a9667b995--
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried so far, show what you understand, let us know where you are stuck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you say "I cannot extract the files ..", do you mean you don't know how to, or that the way you've tried doesn't succeed in extracting the files?  If the latter, please add the code you're attempting to use to extract the files to the text of your question.  If the former, then I'm afraid you're going to have to get to grips with one of the several XML parsers that are available to use with Delphi.

Comment: You might want to look up MTOM and XOP. In case there is no explicit MTOM support for Delphi, consider looking for some MIME library to parse the MIME envelope.

Comment: I tried to search the web but do not know where to start because I have little experience in the use of the parser. I was able to identify the points of beginning and end of each pdf file (Content-ID: <......>) but not to extract the code component pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your example is not an XML file that contains two PDF files. It is (partial) content of a MIME message, which includes three documents, the first one is an XML and ends with </soapenv:Envelope>.

The second and third are PDF documents. You need to extract them, for example using a MIME-capable component such as Indy.

There should be plenty of examples which show how to extract MIME parts of a message using Indy (or other libraries).